# Approximation by $C^\infty$-function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Given $\Delta >0$, $g \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, show that there exists a $\rho \in C^\infty$ with compact support, so that $\|g-\rho\|_{L_2} < \Delta$ and $\|g-\rho\|_{L_1} < \Delta$.

I dont have a real clue how to approch this, I know that C-infinity functions are dense in the $L_p$ spaces, but I dont see any relation between these two norms.

Greetings.

Comment: Have you heard about mollification?

Comment: I thought about it, when I read compact support. But really dont see how to even make an ansatz with that

Comment: look at $g_R = g \chi_{B_R}$, where $\chi_a$ is the characteristic function of $A$. This is a function with compact support. Show that for sufficiently large $R$ this is $\Delta/2$ close to $g$ in both $L^1 $ and $L^2$. Then apply mollification to that $g_R$ and convolute with a mollifier with compact support.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$
(this is only a very rough outline, comment if you need additional help)

First, consider the question on a domain of finite measure, e.g.\ $B_n(0)$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$.

There it is possible, because
the inequality
$$
 \norm{f-g}_{L_1(B_n(0))} \leq C \norm{f-g}_{L_2(B_n(0))}
$$
holds.

We also use that $g \chi_{B_n(0)} \to g$ in both the $L_1$ and the $L_2$ norm.
This is a consequence of $\mathbb R^n = \bigcup_{n\in N} B_n(0)$.

Then you can find a sequence of approximations of $g \chi_{B_n(0)}$,
which can be arbitrarily close to $g$ in both norms.

Comment: but the rhs can become arbitrarily small...

Comment: Sorry, forget my first comment. You need to remark that outside of $B_n$ - for sufficiently large $n$  -- both integrals get as small as desired.

Comment: Thank you. Its indeed a bit rought. $\| f-g \|_{L_1(B_n(0))} \leq C \|f-g \|_{L_2(B_n(0))}$ this is just a consequence that f g lies in both spaces? Why can I find a sequence of approximatons (mollifieres) which can be smaller than epsilon in both norms? How do construct such a sequence?

Comment: no, the inequality is because $B_n(0)$ has finite measure. such an inequality holds always for $L^p$ spaces on a finite measure space.